# How to run games directly from USB in XBOX 360?

Tags: xbox-360

I have XBOX 360. I have not made any changes to the hardware settings. I have need for speed game, which I have copied to USB drive, through install option.  I would like to know, whether the game will always run from the USB drive once the game is installed to the USB drive or should I exclusively run it from USB drive?. If so, then how do I run the game directly from the USB drive?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question. What's the difference between "*always run from the USB drive*" and "*exclusively run it from the USB drive*"?

Answer (score 1):

The game will always require the disc to run the game, even if you install the game onto a flash drive or external drive.

Only purchased games over the Xbox Live market will not require any discs.

The game will read the disc upon entry then run the files off the drive, this is done to increase game speed or solve any issues.
I use it to minimise the noise level, use a little less power and speed up my games, but I still need the discs